# change color of existing image in css

Tags: javascript, css

How can I change the color scale of an existing image into, let's say, "black & #A62A2A" ?

```
<img src="http://g.etfv.co/http://www.google.com" alt="Google" width="16" height="16" />
```

Is it possible in CSS?

Thank you!

Comment: You could take a look at `CSS3 filters` - http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/say-hello-to-webkit-filters--net-23318 Although I think they may only work in Webkit based browsers.

Comment: Google: html image manipulation

Comment: There is a way to manipulate pixels color with canvas, but it can't work if you don't host the image yourself, according to the CORS (Cross-Origin Resource Sharing).